# Linux, execl(), Why do I lose keyboard input to the application?

Tags: linux, qt, keyboard, exec

My Linux program has a name like MyProgram_0001 and newer versions get higher numbers. When started the app looks for a newer version in the same directory and if it finds one calls it via execl(). That works great, but while the mouse continues to work the new version does not get any keyboard input, even if I click in its window beforehand. The calling app is gone, other running programs continue to get keyboard input ... Any ideas ? Actually the program is written a C++ Qt Designer 4.7 application, but that shouldn't be important, or maybe it is :-) ?

OK, some more information ... Here's the code that catches the keys and calls my SLOTs ...

```
// define my own event handler
// capture all key presses ...
bool Layout10::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

        // directly exit on Alt-keys
        if (keyEvent->modifiers()&Qt::AltModifier) return true;

        // normal keyboard
        if ((!(keyEvent->modifiers()&Qt::KeypadModifier))&&(Keyboard_On)) switch (keyEvent->key())
        {
            case Qt::Key_0:         C->Num0ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_1:         C->Num1ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_2:         C->Num2ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_3:         C->Num3ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_4:         C->Num4ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_5:         C->Num5ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_6:         C->Num6ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_7:         C->Num7ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_8:         C->Num8ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_9:         C->Num9ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_X:         C->XButtonClicked_KP();    return true;
            case Qt::Key_Backspace: C->EButtonClicked_KP();    return true;
            case Qt::Key_F1:        C->F1ButtonClicked_KP();   return true;
            case Qt::Key_F2:        C->F2ButtonClicked_KP();   return true;
            case Qt::Key_F3:        C->F3ButtonClicked_KP();   return true;
        }

        // keypad
        if ((keyEvent->modifiers()&Qt::KeypadModifier)&&(Keypad_On)) switch (keyEvent->key())
        {
            case Qt::Key_0:         C->Num0ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Insert:    C->Num0ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_1:         C->Num1ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_End:       C->Num1ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_2:         C->Num2ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Down:      C->Num2ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_3:         C->Num3ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_PageDown:  C->Num3ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_4:         C->Num4ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Left:      C->Num4ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_5:         C->Num5ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Clear:     C->Num5ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_6:         C->Num6ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Right:     C->Num6ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_7:         C->Num7ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Home:      C->Num7ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_8:         C->Num8ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Up:        C->Num8ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_9:         C->Num9ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_PageUp:    C->Num9ButtonClicked_KP(); return true;
            case Qt::Key_Back:      C->XButtonClicked_KP();    return true; // maybe it should have been backslash ?
            case Qt::Key_Delete:    C->EButtonClicked_KP();    return true;
            case Qt::Key_division:  C->F1ButtonClicked_KP();   return true;
            case Qt::Key_multiply:  C->F2ButtonClicked_KP();   return true;
            case Qt::Key_Minus:     C->F3ButtonClicked_KP();   return true;
        }
        return true; // event is NOT given over for further processing
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // other events may be processed further
    }
}
```

The `Keyboard_On` is just a public boolean member of the class which I use to disable the keyboard if a touchscreen is presented to the user. The message handler above is installed like this ...

```
this->installEventFilter(this);
```

... in the constructor of the widget class ... I have one such handler for all the widget classes which make up my dialogs ... Well, it works unless I start the app from itself through execl or `startDetached()` ...

One thing caught my eye in the description of `startDetached()` ... They write that the new process is running in its own environment and behaves like a deamon under Linux. I wonder if that's why I loose the keys ...

Really this puzzles me. Is there some chain of layers the keystrokes have to pass and a way I could debug that and see at what level I loose them ? Thanks !

More info ... I found that I don't loose the keyboard if I call exactly the same binary through execl. If I copy that binary to a different name and call that ... the keyboard is gone. It comes down to a a single letter change in the execl call, only in the second parameter, all else being the same the bug still occurs ... Seems like there's some context which remains the same if the path+binary are the same, but otherwise the keys get sent to the old context and the file called through execl is started within a different context ...

Answer (score 0):

Many applications deal with issues like this by starting with a shell script that runs the binary, instead of the binary itself.  Firefox does this.  You can do the "most recent version" check in the script.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! There's one thing I should have mentioned ... The newer version is (sometimes) uploaded by the already running older version - fetches it from a database when a new verion becomes availlable. A former solution autogenerates a .BAT file (under Windows) and calls that before the old version terminates. The BAT then deletes the old version, renames the new, etc. ... I find the execl() much cleaner, if only I wouldn't loose the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious here: do you perform any kind of clean up before the call to `execl`? Do you call it inside the Qt event loop or do you exit it first?

The `execve(2)` function (which `execl(3)` [is a wrapper of](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl)) does so many kinds of [interesting stuff](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) with the state of the calling process that I'm impressed it even works afterwards:

> execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program loaded. The program invoked inherits the calling process's PID, and any open file descriptors that are not set to close on exec. Signals pending on the calling process are cleared. Any signals set to be caught by the calling process are reset to their default behaviour. The SIGCHLD signal (when set to SIG_IGN) may or may not be reset to SIG_DFL.

Some of that might break the internals of Qt or the X server state or something else entirely. For Qt everything seems like starting from scratch. For everyone else, it's the same process.

If you clean everything up before the "switch", why reuse the same process? Use [`QProcess::startDetached()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#startDetached) instead.

**Edit.** Your last statement is blocking the key presses unconditionally. If the keyboard should be locked only when Keyboard_On or Keypad_On are true, the last statement:

```
 return true; // event is NOT given over for further processing
```

should actually be a `return false`. You only notice this when the app restarts because probably only the newer version of the app is throwing away key events.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll have a look at startDetached() ASAP. Concerning the execl() ... well, I do close running threads before I call it. Otherwise, what can I say, it just worked right from the beginning. Even took me a while to notice that I had lost the keyboard since usually it's mouse based ... This is all learning by doing for me ... Maybe I have to go to fork and kill instead ...

Comment: Well, unfortunately startDetached() got me to the same point ... The new program is started, everything looks great, but keypresses are ignored while mouse input works ... as before. I have the ButtonClicked event linked to the same slot as the KeyPressed event and all of that works alright if the application is started the normal way, but I loose the keys after starting the same thing through execl or startDetached ... Here's what I did for the keys ...

Comment: Seems to be impossible to format this properly. Hope you can copy to your editor. Stupid :-(. `bool Keypad::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

        // directly exit on Alt-keys
        if (keyEvent->modifiers()&Qt::AltModifier) return true;

        // normal keyboard
        if ((!(keyEvent->modifiers()&Qt::KeypadModifier))&&(Keyboard_On)) switch (keyEvent->key())
        {
            case Qt::Key_0:         C->Num0ButtonClicked_KP(); return true; ...`

Comment: This execl thing is definitely neat! I wrote a little app where I call execl from inside the event loop and it works great, keys and all. I'll take a look at the code in a sec.

Comment: That `Keyboard_On` flag, what is it? This seems not to be a problem with `execl`. You might use pastie.org or gists.github.com to share the problematic part of the code, if you want (and are permitted to, of course).

Comment: OK, in order to be able to post formatted text I'll edit my question above ... Thanks for answering. Wish I could vote, but got no account here and that MyOpenID stuff looks like Big Brother sees you everywhere again ... hate such stuff :-( ...

Comment: I now made a very small test app with the same key-event and SLOT logic as the big program ... and the problem is gone, both mouse and keyboard work after execl ... So now I have to find out what is causing this problem. Unfortunately while I know quite a bit about key handling under Win I have no clue under Tux :-) ... strange that all the other things - graphics, database, networking continue to work just fine ... only the keys are gone ... I can pubish code, but not the project as a whole ...

Comment: Hmmm, for starters - I always only test with the latest version, just use different file name for a copy. Then, on the other hand, I understand your reasoning. I intentionally cut off the key events at that point because I try to achive something like a system modal application under Linux which seems to be close to impossible. But in order to make sure I just changed it to false and made some tests. Well, it doesn't work unfortunately. But I found that actually in some cases the keys are still working. It doesn't depend on that exit code, but until now I didn't notice ... I'll check. Thanks !